# I'm trying to drop a dummy variable as type uint8 but I keep getting an error "['False'] not found in axis". Tks for the support as I'm new to this

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, dummy-variable, uint8t

```
data.columns

 Data

dummy = pd.get_dummies(data['High_or_Low_Balance'])
data2 =pd.concat((data, dummy), axis=1)
data2 = data2.drop(['High_or_Low_Balance'], axis=1)
data2.rename(columns={"True":"High_Bank_Balance"}, inplace=True)

print(data2.dtypes)

data2 = data2.drop(['False'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

> KeyError: "['False'] not found in axis"

Comment: What do you think `['False']` means there? That's a list of column names to drop, but there's no column named `False`.

Comment: When I check the dataset the column named False is there with the values 0 and 1. That’s why I’m confused. If I can see it, how can I not drop it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.